# Non-critical CSS is loaded before FCP despite being deferred

Tags: css, pagespeed, lighthouse

I have a website where I'm trying to defer the loading of a non-critical stylesheet.

I am using the below line to achieve this as per various online recommendations:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="non-critical.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'">
```

When I add this at the end of my `<header>` and review the results via Lighthouse, the stylesheet is consistently loaded before the FCP (First Contentful Paint), despite [various articles](https://web.dev/defer-non-critical-css/) stating that should not be the case.

If I try inserting the same line at the end of my  section, I get the "expected" result in the sense that my CSS is loaded after the FCP. However, my understanding is that this form of insertion is not valid.

Does my css insertion need to be modified somehow for this to work when inserted in the header?

Comment: Is this a site with Client Side Rendering or is it a Server Side Rendered page?

Comment: It's a Shopify webshop using the standard Debut theme - I'm not sure if that answers the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FCP is not the same as the onload event. The FCP could be AFTER the onload event in the case of a header image that is loading slow. How about moving this CSS file to the footer?

Comment: This would also be my thinking as it seems to resolve the issue I have. The problem is mainly that my understanding is that it's considered "poor practice" to place a <link> tag with a deferred stylesheet within the <footer> section (i.e. technically within the <body> section. But I'm not sure if there are any practical negative consequences from doing this?

Comment: I think it is fine to put it in the footer.